# Cascade non-inherited properties(e.g. text color) to child elements in webpage without explicitly telling child elements to inherit from parent

Tags: javascript, dom, inheritance

is there a way to cascade non-inherited properties like text color to child elements in a webpage without explicitly telling child elements to inherit from parent node

I am trying to write a small application which restyles a webpage(e.g. google,msn.co.uk). Styles include color, background color by injecting style into the body by doing the following

```
document.body.style.color='green';
```

however elements within the body which contained their own style do not inherit the color e.g. a div element with its own style `<div id="testing" style="color": blue">` still displays blue.

my current understand is that this is an issue of inheritance and not all properties are automatically inherited form the parent container, and for the style to be inherited, one has to change the color to inherit by doing something like

```
document.getElementById('testing').style.color='inherit';
```

in which case it would inherit color  from body. however in this case i would have to go through all child elements explicitly telling them to inherit from parent (i could actually have set these child elements to same color as body)

i guess this is an inheritance issue and not a specificity issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an elegant and nice way to do what you want. But: Just for fun, I tried writing CSS to a `<style>` element I added via JS, so I could use CSS selectors in the declarations and use the `!important` rule. It seemed to work (in Chrome & Safari, anyway), but it's somewhat hacky (but it's always a little hacky to change a site's styles)

```
var overrides = document.createElement("style");
overrides.type = "text/css";
document.head.appendChild(overrides);

overrides.innerText = "body, body * { background: green !important }";
```

Try it in the developer console, and Stack Overflow looks like St Patrick's day!

Again, haven't tested it outside of Chrome & Safari, but it might work for your needs.